# Use rails engine partial within application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, rails-engines

I am using a rails mountable engine called **'Child'** inside the application called **'Parent'**.

I have a **partial 'child/user/_index.html.erb'**

Now I want to **render** this **child's partial in parent controller**. Is it possible?

Means I want to do something like

```
render :partial => 'child/user/index.html.erb'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000460)

```
render :file => 'child/user/index.html.erb' 
###or try '/child/user/index.html.erb'
```

Comment: you can also use render partial

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just `render user/index`

ref http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

> The engine is unable to find the partial required for rendering the
>   comments. Rails looks first in the application's (test/dummy)
>   app/views directory and then in the engine's app/views directory. When
>   it can't find it, it will throw this error. The engine knows to look
>   for blorgh/comments/comment because the model object it is receiving
>   is from the Blorgh::Comment class.

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me:

```
render file: 'child/user/_index.html.erb'
```